# How do I make a text fade in animation for each div on scroll down page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is the animation keeps flashing or I have to implement $(this).off('scroll'); but that can not work as there are more div's below of which need a fade in animation. What is the workaround? I need a fade in animation for the bootstrap cards and id's "ux", "da", and "hs". (option 1, option 2, option 3)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop()); // 0
    var topDivHeight = $(".image").height();
    console.log(topDivHeight); // 794
    var viewPortSize = $(window).height();
    console.log(viewPortSize); //844

    var triggerAt = 709;
    var triggerHeight = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + triggerAt; // 794 - 844 = -50 +709 = 659

    
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight) {
        $('.noimage').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn();
        // $(this).off('scroll');
     }  
});




$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    var topDivHeight2 = $(".noimage").height() + $(".image").height();
    console.log(topDivHeight2);
    var viewPortSize2 = $(window).height();
    console.log(viewPortSize2);

    var triggerAt2 = 700;
    var triggerHeight2 = (topDivHeight2 - viewPortSize2) + triggerAt2;
    
    
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight2) {
        $('#ux').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn();
        // $(this).off('scroll');
     }
    
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
   </head>
   <body>
  <!-- As a heading -->
  
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  
  
  <div class="image container-fluid cont">


  </div>
  <div class = "noimage container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around cont">
    <div class="row cards justify-content-around">
    <div class="card col-sm-3 col-md-12" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/desk.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</p>
          <a href="#ux" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-sm-3 col-md-12" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/data.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card 2</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</p>
          <a href="#da" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-sm-3 col-md-12" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/hosting.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card 3</h5>
          <p class="card-text">lorem</p>
          <a href="#hs" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center overflow-auto align-items-center jumb cont" id="ux">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4">Option 1</h1>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center overflow-auto align-items-center jumb cont" id="da">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4">Option 2</h1>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center overflow-auto align-items-center jumb cont" id="hs">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4">Option 3</h1>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <footer class="py-0 my-0 bg-light fixed-bottom">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-0 mb-0">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#ux" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#da" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Link 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#hs" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Link 3</a></li>
          <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">FAQs</a></li> -->
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="text-center text-muted py-4 mb-0">© 2021 Company, Inc</p>
      </footer>
  </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body { 
     
     min-height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     padding-top: 50px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     overflow-x: hidden;
}

div.card {
    width: 28% !important;
}

div.image {
    padding-top: 50px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image:url('/images/webdesign.jpg');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

div.noimage {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

div.jumb {
    min-height: 100vh;
    /* margin: 0; */
    /* padding: 0; */
    margin-bottom: 145px;
    /* margin-top: 50px; */
}

div#da {
    /* background-color: var(--bs-secondary); */
    background-color: #eee;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}

div#ux {
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}

div#hs {
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}

div.contact {
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 700px;
    
}

footer {
    bottom: 0;
    /* padding-bottom: 145px; */
}


/* Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px) */
@media (max-width: 767.98px)  { 
    
    div.image {
        display: none;
    }

    div.card {
        width: 100vw !important;
    } 
    footer {
        position: relative;
    }
    .nav-item {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    div.contact {
        margin-top: -100px;
        height: 1100px;    
    }
    div.icons {
        display: none;;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
    /* div.cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column !important;
    } */


}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is make a function in javascript for fading text

```js
slider();
function slider(){
document.getElementById("fadingtext").style.color = "rgba(0, 0, 0,"+ document.getElementById("fader").value + ")";
document.getElementById("fadingtext").style.top =  document.getElementById("faderup").value +"px";
document.getElementById("fadingtext").style.position ="absolute";
setTimeout(slider,0);
}
```

```css
#fadingtext{
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="fadingtext">Hello World!</div><br/>
Opacity:<input id="fader" value="1" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.01"type="range"/>
<br/>
Move:<input id="faderup" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="1"type="range"/>
```

This is an example of an opacity changer that you could possibly use. probably make it go up through a variable though

Comment: if you use a variable going from 100-0 do (variable/100) so the opacity wont break

Comment: The problem I am finding is that when the element is in the viewport the code keeps reloading the animation and if I use $(this).off('scroll'); then the animations further down don't work